# Openshift readiness probe not executed

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift

Running a Spring Boot application inside a OpenShift Pod. To execute the readiness and liveness probe, I created an appropriate YAML file. However the Pod fails and responds that he was not able to pass the readiness check (after approximately 5 minutes).

My goal is to execute the readiness probe every 20 minutes. But I assume that it is failing because it adds up the initalDelaySeconds together with the periodSeconds. So I guess that the first check after the pod has been started will be executed after 22 minutes.

Following the related configuration of the readiness probe.

```
readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health
    port: 8080
    scheme: HTTP
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  periodSeconds: 1200
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 60
```

Is my assumption right? How to avoid it (Maybe increase the timeout regarding the kubelet)?

Comment: The readiness probe if defined is what dictates whether you pod is regarded as ready and whether it should be added against the service and traffic sent to it. You shouldn't be adding a delay unless really necessary, and event then not such a long delay as your application will not handle requests until it passes the first time. Why do you feel you need to do this? Do you understand, or are you confusing the purpose of readiness/liveness probes?

Comment: Perhaps review explanation of probes in chapter on monitoring application health in free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is correct and the `initialDelaySeconds` and `periodSeconds` do not sum up. So, the first readinessProbe HTTP call will exactly in 2 min after you start your POD.

I would look for an issue in your app itself, first thing that comes to my mind is that your path is `/actuator/health`, shouldn't it be just `/health`? That is the default in case of Spring Boot Actuator.

If that doesn't help, then the best would be to debug it: `exec` into your container and use `curl` to check if your health endpoint works correctly (it should return HTTP Code 200).